# Как имитировать клик по координатам не двигая при этом мышь на экране?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Как имитировать клик мышью по заданным координатам так чтобы самим курсором мыши на экране можно было продолжать пользоваться.
pyautogui и pymouse не подходят так как они двигают курсор мыши на экране

Comment: если бы я был разработчиком ОС я бы такие "финты ушами" запретил из соображений безопасности ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Windows10

Comment: @MaxU Согласен. :+1:

Comment: На том же C# такое возможно @VictorVosMottor

Comment: Really?! Не знал... Тогда можно попробовать какой-нибудь IronPython вместе с с#. Или сделать dll на шарпе и подгружать на питоне. Как вариант.

Comment: Увы я не силен в шарпе чтобы сделать такой dll @VictorVosMottor

Comment: Ну а код у вас такой есть? (я в шарпе не силен тем более, вообще сижу на линуксе) XD

Comment: @VictorVosMottor нет такого кода на шарпе у меня нет просто знаю что там это можно сделать через Sendmessage

Comment: Забавно, но готовое [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720968/) выложили почти 11 лет назад.

Comment: Тут всё очень зависит от приложения. Некоторые нативные кнопки обрабатывают `WM_CLICK` или `WM_LBUITTTONDOWN` (это такие оконные сообщения), но такое доступно далеко не всем приложениям. А по поводу соображений безопасности, то UAC confirmation, например, не автоматизируется как раз поэтому, даже натуральный клик не срабатывает by design. В остальном, было бы странно запрещать GUI automation полностью.

Comment: Незаметный GUI automation вряд ли получится полноценно, потому что многие действия приводят к появлению фонового окна в фокусе или требуют, чтобы оно в фокусе было, иначе действие не пройдёт. Выход чаще всего один: выносить GUI автоматизацию на отдельный комп. Но там тоже есть свои нюансы, которые надо учесть.